# How to use NSRegular Expression and filter string array correctly in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, regex, string

> Here is my question, I have a string array that contains a bunch of
>   countries:
>
> **let myCountryStart = ["Africa/ABC", "America/BBC", "Asia/CBC", "Pacific/CBA", "Europe/CBB", "Indian/CAB"]**
>
> Is there have any solution to remove the specific words like
>   'Africa', 'America', 'Asia'...etc,.
>       Let the output result looks like the below followings:
>
> **let myCountryEnd = ["ABC", "BBC", "CBC", "CBA", "CBB", "CAB"]**
>
> Here are my code for now...

```
let 1stReplace = myCountryStart.replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "", options: .literal)
let 2ndReplace = 1stReplace.replacingOccurrences(of: "Africa", with: "", options: .literal)
let 3rdReplace = 2ndReplace.replacingOccurrences(of: "Asia", with: "", options: .literal)
```

> I know this is a stupid solution. Hence, I prefer to use **NSRegular Expression**. But I encountered a problem
>   about String & String Array issue.

```
let target = myCountryStart
let regex = "/"
let RE = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "regex", options: .caseInsensitive)
let modified = RE?.stringByReplacingMatches(in: target, options: .reportProgress, range: nil, withTemplate: "") {
    return modified
}
let myCountryEnd = modified
```

> Therefore, I got a warning about I cannot use this method on String
>   array. What should I do to fix it?
>
> Any suggestions or help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks from a Swift rookie.

Comment: `myCountryStart` seems to only have one element. Is that true?

Comment: What is `outputStr`in your old code? Why don't you use that, instead of `myCountryStart` in your new code?

Comment: It should be six elements of a string array. I forgot to revise it.

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks for notice me about that old code error.

Comment: You didn't change it to 6 elements in your edit though...

Comment: @Sweeper lol... I miss it. TnT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `.map` and `.replacingOccurrences` using a regex like `.*/` or `^[^/]*/`:

```
let myCountryStart = ["Africa/ABC", "America/BBC", "Asia/CBC", "Pacific/CBA", "Europe/CBB", "Indian/CAB"]
let myCountryEnd = myCountryStart.map{ $0.replacingOccurrences(of: ".*/", with: "", options: [.caseInsensitive,.regularExpression]) }
print(myCountryEnd)
// => ["ABC", "BBC", "CBC", "CBA", "CBB", "CAB"]
```

The `.*/` pattern will match any 0 or more characters other than line break chars, as many as possible, up to the last `/`.

The `^[^/]*/` pattern will match any chars other than `/` from the start of the string till the first `/`.

Note you do not need the `.caseInsensitive` option, I kept it to show how you may combine several options in the `options` argument.